# Moving Row/Range Up But Not Above A Certain Row

Tags: excel, vba, row

I have the following sub:

```
Sub Rowsup1()

With Selection.EntireRow
    .Cut
    .Offset(.Rows.count - 2).Insert
    .Select
End With

End Sub
```

I would like to prevent the selected row from moving above row 6.  I'm not exactly sure the best way to do this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you meant `.Rows` and not `.Row` fam?

Comment: The current code is correct. It does move the selected row up when the button is selected.  I would like the button to stop functioning before the selected row reaches row 6.

Comment: The current code only works when selecting one row and, in that case, `.rows.count` will always be 1, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will cut the entire row where your `Selection` lives, and then insert it one row up. It stops doing this once your data is in Row 6. It isn't a loop, so if that's what you're looking for (e.g. to click the button once and for the row to keep moving until it hits Row 6), you'll need some modification.

```
Sub Rowsup1()
Dim myRow As Integer

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   With Selection
'   find the currently selected row
    myRow = .Row

'   While myRow doesn't = 6, cut and paste the entire _
    row one row higher than its current location
    If myRow = 6 Then
      'Do nothing
    Else
      .EntireRow.Cut
      Range("A" & myRow - 1).Insert
      .Select
    End If
   End With

   With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
   End With

End Sub
```

I'd recommend changing it to `If myRow <= 6 Then` only so nothing will happen if you've already - for some reason - passed Row 6.

Comment: Genius! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!